# PlayOnLinux won't install anything (17.10)

Tags: wine, playonlinux

After installing Ubuntu 17.10 from scratch, I installed WineHQ and PlayOnLinux following the instructions on the official websites. Then, in PlayOnLinux I installed the Wine version required by my Windows program and after that tried to install that program itself. But PlayOnLinux seems to finish the installation without even starting it: several seconds after I select the .exe file to install, it simply displays the shortcut creation menu (without any files to create a shortcut for) and that's it. And the list of installed programs remains empty, of course. Trying to install other Windows programs gives the same result. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems this version (Ubuntu 17.10) isn't supported any more.
[Please see Ubuntu release cycle schedules here.](https://www.ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle)

I suggest to do a clean install of 18.04 or upgrade your system to 18.04 LTS. Because this is a long term supported version, it will serve you well until the end of Q3 2020.

Consider to back up your system and data, things may go wrong during install/upgrade.

[You can download the installer of 18.04 LTS from here.](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

Also try to avoid 18.10, because the support for ubuntu 18.10 will also end within a year, leaving you in a similar situation like 17.10.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are simulating the correct version of Windows. When PoL is being finicky I either reboot Windows from inside PoL or reboot the computer itself.